# How to do a recursive batch?

Tags: apex, batch

I need to do a batch which calls itself until a condition is true. I don't know how to start. I've tried some things but I got an infinite loop.

The idea is:

1. I have a start date Ex: 2019-01-01
2. Make some things with that date
3. Check if the date is the current date. If true, finish. If false, add 1 day to the start date and run again. (in the 2nd lap the start date would be 2019-01-02, etc.)

How can I achieve this?. I can't do it on a do-while loop, it's neccesary do it in an apex batch.

I hope you can help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: do you want to run execute the batch once in a day?

Comment: no, I need to cover an interval of dates every day

Comment: ok but batch will run only once in a day, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call batch from the previous batch finish() method.
For example,

Initial step to call in developer console or anonymous is `Database.executeBatch(new RecursiveBatch(Date.valueOf('2019-01-01')));`

Then you can use this stub.

```
public class RecursiveBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.AllowsCallouts, Database.Stateful {
private final Date passedDate;

public RecursiveBatch(Date passedDate) {
    this.passedDate = passedDate;
}

public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
    return Database.getQueryLocator( < QUERY >);
}

public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope) {

}

public void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
    if(Date.today() <= this.passedDate) {
        Database.executeBatch(new RecursiveBatch(passedDate.addDays(1)));
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It works! Thank you so much